# Angular 5 - for routed component, how to remove ng-component tag element

Tags: angular, router-outlet

Firstly, I'd like to say I know how to remove component's tag via a selector. Such as use attribute selector like this:

`selector: "div[my-component]"`

I am using Angular 5 now and my problem is that there are components rendered by `router-outlet`, and these components are placed into a `ng-component` element automatically. I am not able to use attribute selector anywhere. How to remove this element? That element causes my CSS breaks.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass host to your router outlet. This will help you to add class, 
So you can apply your css on your outlet with that class.

> @Component({ 
>   selector: 'my-component',
>   templateUrl: './my-component.html', host: {
>       class: 'my-component-container'   } })

Comment: this set class for the parent ng-component, but don't revolve my problem. There are CSS styles like .A>.B>.C, and the ng-component breaks the tree by adding a tag. So the ideal solution is to remove this tag. Thanks for your info!